# Empty a div and then load content into it automatically once user logs in

Tags: php, jquery, session, authentication

I want to use jQuery to empty a content div and load another page into that div once a user has logged in.

I use the normal way that works once a button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").load("DIS-loginform.php");
    });
});
```

I don't want anything to be clicked to load another page in my content div.

This is the login script in my main page sidebar so it will output the username of the user once logged in,

```
<?php  //LOGIN PHP SCRIPT
    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $loginpass =$_POST['password'];
    if((isset($login)) || (isset($loginpass))){
        include("DIS-connect.php");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$login' and password=('$loginpass')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        //echo $count;
        if($count >0){
            echo "Logged in as <button id='user' value='$login'>$login</button>";
            $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $login;
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>sorry login failed</p>";
        }
    }
// LOGIN PHP END ?> `
```

And this is my simple login form that loads into the content div of my main page when the login option is selected.

```
<div id="login">
    <form name="login" action="DIS-home.php" method="POST" 
                onSubmit="return confirm('Continue with Login?');">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th><td><input name="username" type="text" id="username" /></td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Password</th><td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" id="loginbutton" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Also, your MySQL query is injectable and it looks like you're storing plaintext passwords, which is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want anything to be clicked just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").load("DIS-loginform.php");
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").load("DIS-loginform.php");
    });
});
```

And I think you better change your SQL query because it's not save (SQL injections)! Also in the query: there is no hash or something on the password value? So maybe think about using an MD5 or SHA2 encryption?

And the last thing I see for the moment:

Instead of using:

```
if($count >0)
```

Use

```
if($count == 1)
```

This prevents hackers from logging in with an SQL injection that returns multiple rows.

For example:

I can login with using no password and this username:

```
' or 'test'='test' -- '
```

Because it would get a result with all your users and the password part in your query would be commented out.